# Django - media files - security

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-file-upload, django-deployment

I created a Django app with Video files. I'm using Gunicorn & Nginx. A user (not root) that runs the django server.

I restricted the views so only the users with correct permissions can view these. This works fine.

But when watching a video, I can get the url. (../media/videos/video.mp4) [image]

And now everyone with this file-location can see the video.

I'm a little lost now. Do I need to use a package like [django-sendfile2’s](https://django-sendfile2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) ? Or do I need to change my server settings and limit access to the media folders ?

Comment: I'm not a django expert, however in a common case you can solve the tasks like this using `X-Accel-Redirect` nginx feature (see the [example](https://kovyrin.net/2006/11/01/nginx-x-accel-redirect-php-rails/)). As of now this video file is being served directly by nginx itself; your goal is to make it available only after the user passed some credentials check.

Comment: @IvanShatsky, I checked the example and think that [django-sendfile2’s](https://django-sendfile2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) does use this kind a feature. And Nginx is one of the wsgi's they provide.

Comment: I take a look at the documentation link you provide. Yes, I think it is exactly that feature I meant to be used. You'd need an appropriate configuration change from the nginx side too.

Comment: @IvanShatsky, I ended up using the [django-private-storage](https://github.com/edoburu/django-private-storage). Check my answer below ... Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to secure my files using the [django-private-storage](https://github.com/edoburu/django-private-storage) package.  [django-sendfile2’s](https://django-sendfile2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) might also work, but I did find the documentation less explanatory. Following the instructions I installed the packages:

```
pip install django-private-storage
```

And added following lines to the Settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'private_storage',
)
PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'private-media')
```

in the model I added the field:

```
video = PrivateFileField(upload_to='videos/%Y/%m/%d', null=True)
```

In the view I added:

```
from private_storage.views import PrivateStorageDetailView

class PlayJobVideo(PrivateStorageDetailView):
    model = Video
    model_file_field = "video"
    template_name = "index/play_video.html"

    def get_object(self):
        return Video.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['video_id'])
    
    def can_access_file(self, private_file):
        return True
```

And then I wrote a decorator owner_only()

```
def owner-only():
    def decorators(view_func, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            if request.user:
                if video.user == request.user:
                    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return redirect('index:home')
        except:
            return redirect('index:home')
    return wrapper_function
return decorators
```

And the I added this decorator to the view.

```
@method_decorator(owner_only(), name='dispatch')
class PlayVideo(PrivateStorageDetailView):
               ...
```